# I want to open new tab click event with some data with it in react js .Right now am using history.push but it is opening in same tab

Tags: reactjs

```
 history.push({
        pathname: '/TotalHealthSummary',
        search: '?query=abc',
        state: { VesselName: VesselName,data: props.data }
    });
```

Comment: Tell us more about the how the data is received on the other end

Comment: `history.push` is for the current browser tab. You should be able to open a new tab with an anchor element. something like this `<a href="https://some.origin.here/TotalHealthSummary?query=abc" target="_blank">Click Me</a>` ?

Comment: Basically history is for per tab so you can't open it in a new tab but alternatively, you can user <Link to={{ pathname: "/TotalHealthSummary" target="_blank"}>

Comment: i am receiving data from api call and I want post it on next page for that i am using history.push .I have tried using link but it is not taking data with it.